# firebase with auth and without auth security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to create a firebase rule where people can use the database without having to login. But I also want to make a private user node where only the user can acces it by authenticating so far I have something like this. But this trows an error

> Error saving rules - Line 6: Expected '}'.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "newData.exists()"
  },
    "test": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }   
}
```

I do not understand why the above is not possible

But if I do only:

```
  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "newData.exists()"
  }
}
```

This wil work so that anyone can use the current data but I want to have something private like "Test" where the people who authenticated themself only have access to

**So to be clear I want everyone to use the current database but I also want to have some private parts like test only accesable for registered users**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

You cannot add an element after "rules". It should be like:

```
{
  "rules": {
   ...
  }
}
```

and not like

```
{
  "rules": {
    ....   
  },
    ....
}
```

Comment: awesome I understand it now and have fixed my problem

Comment: Nice to know! You may accept my answer, thanks in advance :-)